# Centos 6 Port Crash

Tags: firewall, port

In CentOS 6 server, I set a port and communicate via the TCP protocol.

I opened the port with the following method

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p udp--dport 8443 -j ACCEPT

netstat -tulpn
```

It appears when I query with this command, but, after two or three days this port closes. Why could this be?

When it's closed, you need to add it again and restart the server.

Comment: Did you run `service iptables save` after adding the rules?

Comment: yes, it continues problem